# Filtering out emoji beyond a certain version in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, unicode

I have a PHP application with a MySQL 8 database that (for reasons beyond my control) cannot support UTF-8 text collations beyond `utf8mb4_0900` (Unicode 9).

This presents a problem as users will occasionally enter emoji into text fields that are newer than Unicode 9, resulting in a database error when they hit save.

I don't want to filter out ALL emoji. Is there a way for me to filter out emoji that are newer than Unicode 9, or is this impossible?

Comment: Can you share a [mre] for a character newer than [Unicode 9.0](https://emojipedia.org/unicode-9.0) that is miss-behaving in your application ?   (The `0900` in `utf8mb4_0900` is not related to Unicode 9.0)

Comment: What is the _actual_ error? As Luuk said `0900` is not the version of unicode, it's the version of the collation algorithm in use, and if it hits a codepoint it doesn't know it should just use a default sort order, not raise an error. I don't think that this problem is what you assume it is.

Comment: A table schema wouldn't hurt to see either.

Comment: Also, because I am apparently incapable of thinking about my _actual job_ when there's mystery afoot, the reason why you've pinned yourself to a specific collation algorithm _version_ would be an interesting SO question in itself.

Comment: "Collation" refers to sorting and filtering, not encoding.  "Character set" refers to encoding.  Please provide a sample emoji that is giving you trouble and the query that is in trouble.  Also `SHOW CREATE TABLE` to see if the column is declared with utf8mb4, not simply utf8.